# How do I do get/set method in Python (specifically Trac)

Tags: python, oop

In C-ish languages, I'd mask data storage details with getter/setter methods/functions like:

```
int getFoo();
void setFoo(int value);
```

I have some Python that does:

```
class MyClass:
    def Foo(self):
        ...magic to access foo...
        return value
```

What's the right way to write/name a setter for Foo?  I'm sure it's more idiom than language feature but I'm not sure what's common.  Maybe I need to rename `Foo()` to `getFoo()` and match it with `setFoo()`.  I guess that's OK if that's what is usually done.

Comment: Not sure what [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) has to do with your question, actually.

Comment: If there is a Trac idiom for this that is different from Python, I'd favor Trac's since that's the environment I'm developing my Python for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin **property** function:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 'Initialize self._value with some value or None'        

    def get_foo(self):
        ...magic to access foo...
        return self._value

    def set_foo(self, value):
        ... magic processing for value ...
        self._value = value

    foo = property(get_foo, set_foo)
```

Now you can use access it like this:

```
inst = MyClass()
inst.foo = 'Some value'
print inst.foo
```

It will print:

> > > 'Some value'

Comment: The `property()` form seems much nicer than the `@property` decoration.  Maybe that's a style preference.

Comment: Yeah it's a style preference and for me it's easier to remember

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property). This is pulled directly from the docs:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Now you can do...

```
c = C()
c.x = "a"
print c.x
>>> "a"
del c.x
```

Keep in mind that in Python versions prior to Python 3 (e.g., Python 2.7) you need to make sure that your object is a new-style class (it must derive from `object`) for it to support properties like this. Granted, you probably should be using new-style classes for all your classes anyway...

Comment: To elaborate, the advantage of using `@property` is that it is syntactically identical to regular attribute access from the client side. You can thus change from regular attributes to properties and back again without affecting your API.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need to use getters and setters in Python.

If however, you want to expose the result of a procedure as a property, you can use the [`@property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        # operation
        return value

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        # operation storing value
```

It is more common to just store the value of `foo` in an attribute. This can be calculated in the `__init__` instance initializer:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = someCalculationDeterminingFoo()
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  If MyClass has properties Foo and Bar that may change over the lifetime of an instance, how can I set them when the object is created?

Comment: @ChrisNelson: How do they change? Can something else set them when they do? Otherwise, use `@property` decorators, or `getFoo` + `setFoo` methods; the latter when `getFoo()` needs to take arguments.